# I want to setup a DRM based video stream with both widevine and play ready

Tags: video-streaming, azure-media-services, drm, widevine, playready

We want to add DRM encryption in our content - basically teststreams to verify our players in long run. So we need to setup our own test streams with Playready and widevine. Is it feasible to setup our own system. All the documents that I see online redirects to some third party drm solution providers.
I am completely new on the domain, Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it for both Widevine and Playready if you really want to - Google and Microsoft have partner programs and SDK's.

However, it is a very specialised area and you may want to add FairPlay to support apple devices at some point also, increasing the complexity. The setup, integration and ongoing support will be time consuming and many prefer to concentrate their resources on their core business, given that there are quote a few multi DRM vendors now catering for most price points.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Our intent is to test our players with different combination of DRM , packaging and codecs. For that we need to setup different test streams that will be locally deployed in the test environment.  For example one of our requirement is to test a video stream with AAC codec, HLS packaging and Widevine DRM. Currently we are using some open source resources available online. Instead of that we would like to develop our own test stream with DRM. Is it feasible/worth it to setup our own DRM stream for testing purpose.

Comment: You can certainly use an open source packager, like Shaka packager, for example and an account with a Pay as You Go multi DRM vendor like EZDRM or Buy DRM to build some test stream which are encrypted with the leading DRM's.